# How to put text with respect to plot/figure/device region in terms of coordinate from 0 to 1?

Tags: r, graphics

https://bootstrappers.umassmed.edu/bootstrappers-courses/pastCourses/rCourse_2014-09/resources/helpfulGuides/Rfigurelayout.pdf

The above doc shows plot region, figure region, and device region.

Suppose these regions are mentally mapped to coordinates from 0 (the bottom or the left) to 1 (the top or the right). How to put text in this definition of coordinates on these three regions in basic R, respectively?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking is how to place text anywhere in the plotting window, using proportional device co-ordinates. This is actually how text works in the grid graphic system:

```r
library(grid)

grid.newpage()

grid.draw(rectGrob(gp = gpar(lwd = 2)))
grid.draw(textGrob("(0.1, 0.1)", 0.1, 0.1, gp = gpar(cex = 2, col = "red2")))
grid.draw(textGrob("(0.5, 0.5)", 0.5, 0.5, gp = gpar(cex = 2, col = "blue")))
grid.draw(textGrob("(0.9, 0.9)", 0.9, 0.9, gp = gpar(cex = 2, col = "green2")))
```

[image]

However, if you want to do the same thing in base R graphics, I think you would need to write a wrapper around `text` that queries the graphics device and converts your device space co:ordinates to user co-ordinates, then draws the text with clipping off.

Here is such a function (called `dtext` to denote "device text")

```r
dtext <- function(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, label, ...) {
  margins <- par("omi") + par("mai")
  plotsize <- par("pin")
  devsize  <- dev.size()
  usr_space <- par("usr")
  usr_y <- devsize[2] / plotsize[2] * (diff(usr_space[3:4]))
  y_min <- usr_space[3] - usr_y * margins[1]/devsize[2]
  
  usr_x <- devsize[1] / plotsize[1] * (diff(usr_space[1:2]))
  x_min <- usr_space[1] - usr_x * margins[2]/devsize[1]
  
  text(x = x * usr_x + x_min,
       y = y * usr_y + y_min,
       label = label,
       xpd = NA,
       ...)
}
```

This allows:

```r
plot(1:10, 1:10)

dtext(x = 0.1, y = 0.1, label = "(0.1, 0.1)", cex = 2, col = "red2")
dtext(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, label = "(0.5, 0.5)", cex = 2, col = "blue2")
dtext(x = 0.9, y = 0.9, label = "(0.9, 0.9)", cex = 2, col = "green2")
```

[image]

This seems like a pretty useful function, and I'm surprised it doesn't exist already, so thanks for the OP.

<sup>Created on 2022-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I agree with your last comment. R basic library is quite cumbersome with a badly designed API, in terms of missing useful functions, and bad argument defaults, etc.

Comment: My question also asks about how to plot to the 0-1 mental coordinate within the other two regions as well, respectively. Please update your answer for those as well?

Comment: @user1424739 these two regions are variable. In fact, by default the outer margin is set to 0., so there is no outer margin area. The above function _does_ plot in the margin (and outer margin if it exists). The point is that it effectively "ignores' the fact that there are different regions within the plotting device, and just draws text wherever you want. Or perhaps I misunderstand you? Can you describe what input/ output you are expecting?

Comment: For example, if input is c(0,0), I want to plot two points, one at the bottom-left corner of the plot region and the other at the bottom-left of the figure region.

Comment: @user1424739 in that case, what input would you use for a point at the bottom middle of your plot? Surely you need an x and y co-ordinate for each point?. You could get this result using my function with `dtext(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 0), label = c("labrl1", "label2"))`

Comment: But I need the plotted point be at c(0, 0) wrt to the plot region. and at (0, 0) wrt to the figure region. Your function is just for c(0, 0) wrt to the device region.

Comment: @AllanCameron this command _does_ exist, it is `grconvertX`/`grconvertY` but seeing as how op [does not allow one to introduce new commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791103/how-to-use-text-mimic-axis#comment126869231_71791807), i can see how this would be challenging to answer

Comment: Thanks @rawr. I _thought_ there should be a function like this already, but I'd never come across it, and it's difficult to find the right search terms to look for it. Anyway, it doesn't seem to be what the OP wanted here.